# How to configure Apache tomcat with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Can someone tell me steps and permissions that are required for running maven project in intellij idea with tomcat to debug server project in windows? I have tried but intellij failed to deploy the war file. I guess there are some certain steps and permissions which I am missing.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this.  Can you tell us on which step are you stuck?  Briefly, you would need to build your Maven project with debugging and breakpoints enabled.  Then, you need to tell IntelliJ how to hook into Tomcat.

Comment: It is possible to create Run configuration to start Tomcat and deploy your war to it in Intellij. For that you need to set up path to Tomcat installation and then configure deployment details like how to build your war and to what path to deploy

Comment: I will be grateful if you can mention the required steps to create a working run configuration. I have tried but nothing worked. Intellij can start the tomcat server but it is unable to deploy the war file. And I do not see the project folder in my tomcat\webapp\myApp folder inside the tomcat server installation folder. I set a run configuration and selected tomcat server> selected the tomcat home path and selected artefect: war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid that you built artifact failed. You can check tomcat's logs in the folder path like:

> C:\Users\user\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_tomcat\logs

Normally, I will create tomcat as below (of course, it run well)

**1. Create local tomcat** 
[image]

**2. Config tomcat home** 
Click Configure button, browse to tomcat_home where you installed tomcat

**3. add artifact (Deployment tab)**
 [image]
Ok, done. Now you can start tomcat. If building artifact is correct, your application will be up (let's check tomcat's log as I pasted above).

Comment: [2018-07-23 08:52:57,755] Artifact x-service:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-07-23 08:52:57,756] Artifact x-service:war exploded: Deploy took 29,249 milliseconds

Comment: Now I have tried to login as admin and check it into the tomcat server but I dont see my application there.

Comment: @user269156 you mean that did u login as admin in tomcat manager ?

Comment: im not sure how you performed, but if you start tomcat with intellij by the way above in my answer. I cannot access tomcat manager.

Comment: in order to resolve configuration with tomcat server, you should create new web project (simple proj) first, start tomcat with the project. If the process is successful, i think you go back building artifact. let's open all files in logs folder